# Why my TicTacToe game doesn't complete running the codes? (Python 2.7.9)

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

When I run my codes,it gets stuck after I choose wether to play first or not.
So, here is the codes:

```
#TicTacToe game
import random

null = ''
new = ['','','','','','','','','']
Player = ''
Computer = ''


#X or O signs
def sign(Player, Computer):
    Player = raw_input('Please choose either X or O:')
    while Player not in ('X','x','O','o'):
        print ('Not the appropriate choice!')
        Player = raw_input('Please choose either X or O;')
    if Player == 'X' or Player == 'x':
        print ('You have chosen X!')
        Computer = 'O'
    else:
        print ('You have chosen O!')
        Computer = 'X'
    return Player.upper(), Computer.upper()


#Which player will play first
def WhoPlaysFirst():
    shift = None
    while shift not in ('yes','Yes','YES','no','No','NO'):
        shift = raw_input('Do you want to play first? Yes or No:')
        if shift == 'yes' or shift == 'Yes' or shift == 'YES':
            return 1
        elif shift == 'no' or shift == 'No' or shift == 'NO':
            return 0
        else:
            print ('It is invaild choice!')

def TheBoard(Move):


    print ("=================================")
    print ("[*]        :        :         [*]")
    print "[*]  " , Move[1] ,       "    :   " , Move[2] ,         "   :    " , Move[3] ,            "   [*]"
    print ("[*]        :        :         [*]")
    print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
    print ("[*]        :        :         [*]")
    print "[*]  " , Move[4] ,       "    :   " , Move[5] ,         "   :    " , Move[6] ,            "   [*]"
    print ("[*]        :        :         [*]")
    print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
    print ("[*]        :        :         [*]")
    print "[*]  " , Move[7] ,       "    :   " , Move[8] ,         "   :    " , Move[9] ,            "   [*]"
    print ("[*]        :        :         [*]")
    print ("=================================")


def winner_Computer():
    print ("Sorry you lost!")

def winner_Player():
    print("You won!")

def FirstMove_Player(Player, Computer, new):
    while winn(Player, Computer, new) is None:
        Turn = Player_Turn(Player, new)
        new[int(Turn)] = Player
        TheBoard(new)
        if winn(Player, Computer, new) != None:
            break
        else:
            pass
        print("The computer will choose..")
        C_Turn = Computer_Turn(Player, Computer, new)
        print C_Turn
        new[int(C_Turn)] = Computer
        TheBoard(new)
    Pr = winn(Player, Computer, new)
    if Pr == 1:
        winner_Player()
    elif Pr == 0:
        winner_Computer()
    else:
        print("It is a tie :/")


def FirstMove_Computer(Player, Computer, new):
    while not winn(Player, Computer, new):
        print("The computer will take..")
        C_Turn = Computer_Turn(Player, Computer, new)
        print C_Turn
        new[C_Turn] = Computer
        TheBoard(new)
        if winn(Player, Computer, new) != None:
            break
        else:
            pass
        Turn = Player_Turn(Player, new)
        new[int(move)] = Player
        TheBoard(new)
    Pr = winn(Player, Computer, new)
    if Pr == 1:
        winner_Player()
    elif Pr == 0:
        winner_Computer()
    else:
        print("It is a tie :/")


def winn(Player, Computer, new):
    Possibilities = ((1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9),(1,4,7),(2,5,8),(3,6,9),(1,5,9),(3,5,7))
    for i in Possibilities:
        if new[i[1]] == new[i[2]] == new[i[3]] != null:
            Winner = new[i[1]]
            if Winner == Player:
                return 1
            elif Winner == Computer:
                return 0
            if null not in new:
                return 'Tie!'
    if null not in new:
        return 'Tie'
    return None


def Player_Turn(Player, new):
    Move = raw_input("Which box you want to put in?:")
    while True:
        if Move not in ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'):
            print("That is invalid move")
            Move = raw_input("Which box you want to put in?:")
        elif new[int(Move)] != null:
            print ("This box is already taken, please choose another one")
            Move = raw_input("Which box you want to put in?:")
        else:
            return int(Move)



def Computer_Turn(Player, Computer, new):
    choicest = [9, 7, 5, 1, 3]
    blank = []
    for i in range(0,9):
        if new[i] == null:
            blank.append(i)

    for i in blank:
        new[i] = Computer
        if winn(Player, Computer, new) is 0:

            return i
        new[i] = null

    for i in blank:
            new[i] = Player
            if winn(Player, Computer, new) is 1:

                return i
            new[i] = null

    return int(blank[random.randrange(len(blank))])


def Enterance():
    #Intro. to the game
    print ("WELCOME TO...")
    print ("############         ##############                #############")
    print ("############         ##############                #############")
    print ("    ####    WWWWWWWWW     ####         XXXXXXXXX        ####")
    print ("    ####OOO WWW*****W     ####         XXX&&&&&&        ####         WWWWWWWWWWW")
    print ("    ####OOO WWWWWWWWW     ####         XXXXXXXXX        ####         WWW     WWW")
    print ("    ####    WWW           ####GGGGGGG  XXX              ####DDDDDDDD WWWWWWWWWWW")
    print ("    ####O#O WWW           ####G@@@@@G  XXX              ####DDDDDDKD WW%%%%%%%WW")
    print ("    ####O#O WWW           ####G@@@@@G  XXX              ####D    DKD WWWWWWWWWWW")
    print ("    ####O#O WWWWWWWWW     ####G@@@@@@GGGGGGXXXXX        ####D    DKD WW")
    print ("    ####O#O WWW*****W     ####G@@@@@@@@@@@GX&&&&        ####DDDDDDKD WW")
    print ("    ####O#O WWWWWWWWW     ####GGGGGGG GGGGGGXXXXX       ####DDDDDDKD WWWWWWWWWWW")
    print ("All you have to do is to choose the number so that you can make your move")
    print ("And here is how your Game Board will look like:")
    print ("                                    ")
    print ("====================================")
    print ("[*]        :          :          [*]")
    print ("[*]    1   :     2    :     3    [*]")
    print ("[*]        :          :          [*]")
    print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
    print ("[*]        :          :          [*]")
    print ("[*]    4   :     5    :     6    [*]")
    print ("[*]        :          :          [*]")
    print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
    print ("[*]        :          :          [*]")
    print ("[*]    7   :     8    :     9    [*]")
    print ("[*]        :          :          [*]")
    print ("====================================")
    print ("                LET'S              START                THE GAME!!             ")


def Main(Player, Computer, new):
    Enterance()
    Move = sign(Player, Computer)
    Player = Move[0]
    Computer = Move[1]
    b = WhoPlaysFirst()
    if b == 1:
        print ("You will play first.")
        print ("Lets start. Here is our Game Board!")
        TheBoard(new)
        FirstMove_Player(Player, Computer, new)
    elif b == 0:
        print ("The computer will play first")
        print ("Lets begin the game. That is our Game Board!")
        TheBoard(new)
        FirstMove_Computer(Player, Computer, new)
    else:
        pass


Main(Player, Computer, new)
raw_input("Tab Enter to exit")
```

And here is the error message i get when the codes stuck at some point:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HANY\Documents\Nona CS\MyTicTacToe3.py", line 214, in <module>
    Main(Player, Computer, new)
  File "C:\Users\HANY\Documents\Nona CS\MyTicTacToe3.py", line 203, in Main
    TheBoard(new)
  File "C:\Users\HANY\Documents\Nona CS\MyTicTacToe3.py", line 50, in TheBoard
    print "[*]  " , Move[7] ,       "    :   " , Move[8] ,         "   :    " , Move[9] ,            "   [*]"
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can someone please tell what I've done wrong and how to fix it?
I would appreciate it thanks!

Comment: the error you describe don't seems to be relative with your code.

Comment: It's a bit difficult to see, but in one of your calls to `TheBoard` the `move` variable does not have length 9. You should fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `new`is a List and the first index of a list is 0.
You should change your `def TheBoard(Move)`. It should start with `Move[0]` and not `Move[1]` because `Move[9]` ist the 9th index of your list but the maximum is 8.

The same problem should be in `def winn(Player, Computer, new)` with `new[i[1]]`.

See also [THIS](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/lists) to learn how to use lists.

Edit:
You have the same problem in `def Player_Turn(Player, new)`.
When you correct it there too, it should work.